# hyperledger fabric set ORDERER_CA using the bash

Tags: bash, hyperledger-fabric

I am writing the bash script to run hyperledger fabric setup with 2 organisation, and i am trying to install chain-code to. It works well in manual, but i have create the bash script, i am trying to export ORDERER_CA using below command. please suggest me.

```
 docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051" -it cli  export ORDERER_CA=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

facing the error

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"export\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export the variable while the docker is running.
You should set the environment variable inside the docker-compose.yaml environments section and then run the docker with docker-compose.